# It seems packages are installed after the Yocto ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND, why?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I add a task to the ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND which creates a copy of the opkg package status file. This always worked as expected (Poky Thud), but now using Poky Kirkstone, the created copy (during postprocess) in the image differs from the original file in the image.

This means that after (or during) ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND the package configuration is changed.

When checking the logfile 'run.buildhistory_get_imageinfo', the value of ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND is shown. After my task, only the following 3 other tasks are present:

- set_user_group
- sort_passwd
- rootfs_reproducible

I do not know in which order the rootfs post process tasks are executed. But I assume in the order they are listed.

As far as I know, the last three tasks do not alter the configuration of installed packages. So which task is doing this, and is there any other option to add a 'real' post process task before the image is created ?